# glm::vec2 Not Allowing Operations

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, glm-math

In using GLM, I have been able to use operations on vectors and matrices (+, -, *, /).  For some reason in the following line of code, it will not let me do any operations:

```
glm::vec2 fixedPos = position + dimensions/2;  // <- Error is on the '/'
```

*("position" and "dimensions" are both of type "const glm::vec2")*

**Error:**
no operator "/" matches these operands;  operand types are: const glm::vec2 / int

*(replacing "/" with any other math operator will result in the same error)*

I find it annoying and strange why this is not working.  The error is saying my syntax is incorrect, when what it asks for is what I put!  If you see the issue, please post the answer below.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
glm::vec2 fixedPos = position + dimensions / 2.0f;
```

`vec2` is actually a `typedef` to `highp_vec2` which is a `typedef` to `tvec2<float, highp>` (cf. `glm/detail/type_vec.hpp`)

Comment: Thanks, that did work!  I am confused why Visual Studio would tell me that the correct syntax is `const glm::vec2 / int`, when in reality I need to put `const glm::vec2 / float`.